# Marketing Cloud Query not importing Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I created a new campaign, added 1500 contacts. I moved into Marketing Cloud and I created a query to move data in for a single send.

```
SELECT
c.[ID] as [CID],
c.[Name] as [CampaignName],
cm.[FirstName] as [FirstName],
cm.[Email] as [Email],
cm.[Member_ID__c] as [CMID],
cm.[ContactID] as [Contact ID]
FROM
[Campaign_Salesforce] c
JOIN
[CampaignMember_Salesforce] cm  
on c.[Id] = cm.[CampaignID]
JOIN
[Contact_Salesforce] ct
on ct.[ID] = cm.[Contact_ID__c]
WHERE 
c.id = '7011I0000000aaaAAA' (anonymised)
```

When I run this I get 3 contacts in my Data Extension.

What have I missed? My thoughts are that perhaps the query only looks at data in SFMC and not in SFDC - which is counter to what I thought this was doing.

Please do go for the stupid things because I'm really not an expert and this is all new to me.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second join? It doesn’t seem to do anything. Can you try removing it?

Comment: @zuzannamj I did and it increased to 975, still missing about 300. I copied someone else's query as a starting point.

Comment: Where are you running this, Query Studio or Automation Studio? Maybe it’s got to do with your DE if you’re using Automation Studio

Comment: It's just a one off so I am running it using "Run Once" button

Comment: What is the primary key of your target DE?

Comment: Contact ID @zuzannamj

Comment: Do you synchronise all contacts into SFMC or just a subset? Any chance the records you're missing aren't synchronised across into the Contact_Salesforce DE?

Comment: A subset. If I pull a query shouldn't it import the items?